# Passing URL parameter into the controller - laravel

Tags: laravel

I currently pass in the `id` into the URL `blog.dev/image?=1`. Within this page I need to pass the 1 into a controller function.

What I currently do to achieve this is use a hidden input field and pass the id into the value. However I don't imagine this is a good way to do it as the user could change this value through the inspector.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/image', 'imguploadController@index');
Route::post('/image', 'imguploadController@store');

public function index(Request $request) {
    $imgID = $request->query('id');
    return view('imgupload.create', compact('imgID'));
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $imgID = $request->query('id');
}
```

The `$imgID` returns `null` whenever I run the store function. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters + https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: `$query_string_array = $request->input();`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with your URL params which you already have (but kinda bad formatted).

Your current URL is

```
blog.dev/image?=1
```

it should be

```
blog.dev/image?id=1
```

and later on in your Controller you can get that value

```
$imgID = $request->id;
```

Sometimes may happen that this param is not set so it's wise to check if that param exist

```
if ($request->has('id')) {
    $imgID = $request->id;
    //
}
```

Same rules apply with post/get requests from form/ajax.